# Boot CD for Kali Linux gets stuck on startup screen?

Tags: windows, boot, kali-linux, bootable-media

I've been trying to dual-boot my 64-bit Windows 10 Asus PC with Kali Linux, but for some reason whenever I burn my writeable CDs with Power ISO with the 64-bit ISO from the Kali Linux website and select "Use a Device" from the Advanced Startup Options, it goes into the Asus startup screen and it stops. Nothing happens. I've waited for 2 hours and nothing. If I do a hard shutdown with the power button I can still access windows 10. I've also tried BIOS. I went all the way to reset my whole PC and the same problem happened again.